# How to stop e-mail from sending to wrong recipient

Tags: lotus-notes

I am using Lotus Notes 8.5 version.

My question, how can I stop e-mail if I accidentally sent to wrong recipient. If yes, how many minutes after I sent to ensure that the recipient will not receive my e-mail.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This action is detailed in the help topic "Recalling a message".
In the sent view:
1. Select the message
2. Above the message list, click "Recall Message" (If this button does not display, your administrator has disabled it)
3. If the message was sent to more than one recipient, select the recipient to recall it from.
4. Optional, to recall the message from a recipient who has already read it, select "Recall the message even if it has been read"
5. Make sure that "Send me a status report for each recipient" is checked so you get confirmation.

Comment: You also might want to mention: `Note: For a message recall to work, both you and the message recipient must be using the Release 8 mail application template (Mail8.ntf) on a Release 8 Domino server, and the message recipient must have the basic mail preference Allow others to recall mail sent to me selected.`. So this is only a Lotus 2 Lotus solution. See [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.notes85.help.doc%2Fmail_recall_t.html)